# How to convert string to int in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey guys todays my first day with python and im trying to do what seems like a simple thing to  me but it keeps giving me errors. I am reading a number from a text file and trying to convert it into an int. This is my code:

```
f=open('commentcount.txt','r')
counts = f.readline()
int(counts)
counts = counts + 1
print(counts)
```

i am getting this error: counts = counts + 1
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Can somone please tell me what I am doing wrong?  thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must assign the value of `int(counts)` to `counts` in order to keep changes. Note that `int(...)` doesn't modify the variable you pass in.

```
counts = int(counts)
```

Be sure that `f.readline()` return an string that "represents" a `int`.